# Vim Conque Gdb backspace deletes whole word

Tags: vim, terminal, gdb, backspace

When I press a backspace in the ConqueTerm running gdb then it deletes a whole word instead of a single character. How can I make the backspace delete only a single character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More digging revealed the problem. I had this line in .inputrc:

`"\b": backward-kill-word`

Interesting thing is that it did not make any problems in rxvt.

Answer (score 0):

My .inputrc contained a different line with the same effect:

```
"\C-?":"\C-W"
```